# How to copy a file from Docker directory to S3 bucket using Python3

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, python-3.6

In my Docker file below is code, when my Python code is executed using AWS Cloud Formation & Pipeline, it creates a `.txt file (abc.txt) under /proj`.

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /proj
```

The Docker session terminates when the Python job execution is completes. So, just before completing Python job, I want to copy the abc.txt (from Docker) file to AWS S3 bucket. Is this possible? How can I achieve this.

Already tried this

```
RUN aws s3 COPY /proj/ s3://filepath_on_s3
```

First 2 lines of my Docker file:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /proj
```

**Solution**: With below lines of code now i'm able to transfer my file (which is in docer vm) to S3 bucket. Need to setup awscli on docker after that using boto3 in PY code used upload_file command.

```
####Docker file
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y awscli
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=ABBXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XARXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx
ENV AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2
###Python code
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Bucket('Mybucket').upload_file('/proj/'+logfile, 'Logs/'+logfile)
```

Comment: how you run the python script?

Comment: If you want to run the aws cli from within the docker build process , you will first need to install the CLI in the docker image as part of your build process. I would rather suggest to copy the text file to a mounted location as part of your build process and then as part of your next step ( which is outside the docker build process ) copy the file using the standard aws s3 copy method....

Comment: when I deploy my code to cloud formation, it is internally calling a Lambda. Lambda executing the code using docker vm and there it is generating one .txt file. This txt file I want to copy from docker to S3 before job completes.

Comment: Solution included above..  thanks for your help.